# Sort a binary file without loading it into memory or using a temporary file

Tags: c, sorting

I had a silly assignment:

> You are given a binary file FLOATS.DAT of unknown length, type `float`
>   data has been written in it. Write a program which sorts the data in
>   the file (the output is a sorted file FLOATS.DAT). You need to sort it
>   without loading the file into memory, or by using a temporary file.
>   Use the [Shell sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort).

Obviously by using a temp. file it would be easy, even more if you could load it into memory.

Here is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// sizeof(float) = 4 on my machine

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    size_t sajz = sizeof(float); // for convenience 
    int n; // total number of floats in the file

    FILE *dat;

    dat = fopen("FLOATS.DAT", "r+b");

    if (dat == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while opening.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // find the number of floats in the file
    fseek(dat, 0, SEEK_END);
    n = ftell(dat)/sajz;
    rewind(dat);

    float tjmh, tx;
    int i,j,h;

    // standard shell sort algorithm, the hard part is when I have to
    // read a position I first have to jump to it, then read it,
    // same when writing to a location
    for (h = n/2; h>0; h/=2)
    {
        for (i=h; i<n; i++)
        {
            j = i;

            fseek(dat, i*sajz, SEEK_SET);
            fread(&tx, sajz, 1, dat);
            rewind(dat);

            fseek(dat, (j-h)*sajz, SEEK_SET);
            fread(&tjmh, sajz, 1, dat);
            rewind(dat);

            for (; j>=h && tx < tjmh; j -= h)
            {

                fseek(dat, j*sajz, SEEK_SET);
                fwrite(&tjmh, sajz, 1, dat);
                rewind(dat);

                // this was tricky to figure out
                // I need the value of `j` after it has been
                // subtracted from h
                fseek(dat, (j - 2*h)*sajz, SEEK_SET);
                fread(&tjmh, sajz, 1, dat);
                rewind(dat);
            }

            fseek(dat, j*sajz, SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&tx, sajz, 1, dat);
            rewind(dat);

        }
    }

    fclose(dat);

    return 0;
}
```

Can this be improved in any way?

---

Code snippet to generate the file with numbers 2.0, 3.0, 10.0, 4.0, 1.0, 7.0, 9.0, 5.0, 6.0, 8.0

```
int main()
{
    FILE *dat;

    dat = fopen("FLOATS.DAT", "wb");

    float a;
    if (dat)
    {
        a = 2.00;
        fwrite(&a, sizeof(float), 1, dat);
        a = 3.00;
        fwrite(&a, sizeof(float), 1, dat);
        a = 10.00;
        fwrite(&a, sizeof(float), 1, dat);
        a = 4.00;
        fwrite(&a, sizeof(float), 1, dat);
        a = 1.00;
        fwrite(&a, sizeof(float), 1, dat);
        a = 7.00;
        fwrite(&a, sizeof(float), 1, dat);
        a = 9.00;
        fwrite(&a, sizeof(float), 1, dat);
        a = 5.00;
        fwrite(&a, sizeof(float), 1, dat);
        a = 6.00;
        fwrite(&a, sizeof(float), 1, dat);
        a = 8.00;
        fwrite(&a, sizeof(float), 1, dat);

        fclose(dat);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can use an array here as well.

Comment: Where did this assignment come from? Would `mmap()` be considered "loading the file into memory"?

Comment: By "Shell Sort" I though it meant use the sort built into your shell. But what I think it now means you need to sort a stream of floating point numbers using "shell sort". Obviously you have to read it into memory the point of not loading it is to force you to sort a stream of data.

Comment: Of course, in reality if one is "given [implying by someone else] a binary file FLOATS.DAT of unknown length, type `float` data", one first has to determine whether it's possible to unambiguously determine the non-portable bit representation that was used to write it, otherwise it's of no use... and even if you can figure that out, your system might differ, meaning you'd have to convert to its representation, which isn't necessarily trivial. All of which supports your conclusion that - like so many others - it's a "silly assignment". ;)

Comment: @underscore_d: in practice, [the IEEE-754 floating point representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Interchange_formats) is near-universal.  gcc defines macros for float endianness, but IDK if that's an issue on real CPUs the way integer endianness is.

Comment: @200_success `mmap()` wouldn't work since we didn't learn about it prior to that. But  after reading about it I think it would be unfit for this since it's not universally available.

Comment: @underscore_d Maybe I should have mentioned. When not specified, it's implied that the system uses big-endian. Was that your concern?

Comment: @LokiAstari Yes, using the shell sort algorithm. We were not allowed to load it into memory.

Comment: @underscore_d: I have written some code that transforms native floats to/from IEEE binary representation using standard functions. https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer/blob/master/src/BinaryRep/FltBinRep.h (of course this is a noop if your system is already IEEE compliant). `net2HostIEEE()` and `host2NetIEEE()`

Comment: @PeterCordes: Actually it's not as simple as that. Unfortunately lots of systems use 80 bit floats (because that is a standard size of FPU that is installed). If you use "double" on these systems this gets truncated down to the standard IEEE Double precision (ie 64 bit) value when saved to a memory location. But if you use a "long double" this does not get transformed into the IEEE Quad precision (ie 128 bit value) it is usually stored as 80 bit zero padded. This padded value is not IEEE **Interchange format**. Unless you start flipping some compiler floating point flags.

Comment: @LokiAstari Thanks for the link - I'll have to ponder that on a day when I have some spare brain power! I had to write a class before to convert to/from IEEE754 80-bit and store it in packed binary format. However, I did it all 'by hand' rather than using the stdlib. It definitely avoids UB, though ;-) but for that reason, it probably isn't so fast... Well, it works, and I was proud of it at the time :-)

Comment: @LokiAstari: That's what I get for keeping it brief. >.<  Yes,`long double` is the same as `double` on Windows, but  the raw x87 80-bit type on Linux.  ([`sizeof(long double)` = 12 bytes in the 32bit SysV ABI (2 bytes of padding)](https://godbolt.org/g/6uyIYm), or 16 bytes in the x86-64 SysV ABI (6B of padding)).  As you say, it would be a mistake to use raw `long double` in a serialization format.  However, **this question is only talking about `float`, which is 32-bit IEEE in every ABI I've heard of**.

Comment: @underscore_d: and as LokiAstari says, when x87 code is used to evaluate `float` or `double` expressions (instead of SSE which is the default in 64bit code), temporaries are typically kept at 80-bit precision.  The [`FLT_EVAL_METHOD` macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits/FLT_EVAL_METHOD) is supposed to tell you what can happen.  IDK how reliable it is :P  See also [gcc's `-ffloat-store` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) to get strict rounding of temporaries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)

> ```
>             fseek(dat, i*sajz, SEEK_SET);
>             fread(&tx, sajz, 1, dat);
>             rewind(dat);
> ```

You do this three times.  The general rule is first time write, second time copy, third time refactor into a common function.  Note that if there is sufficient commonality, you may create the common function with only two uses (e.g. with the `fwrite` version).  Make a function:

```
void read_at_position(FILE *source, size_t position, size_t size, void *datum)
{
    fseek(source, position * size, SEEK_SET);
    fread(datum, size, 1, source);
    rewind(source);
}
```

I made `datum` a `void *` because that's what `fread` takes.  This way you don't have to write a new function if you change the `datum` type.

Now you can rewrite the original section (and the other four) like

```
            read_at_position(dat, i, sajz, &tx);
```

If you're worried about the overhead, you could create a macro instead

```
#define READ_AT_POSITION(source, position, size, datum) \
    do {\
        fseek(source, (position) * (size), SEEK_SET);\
        fread(datum, size, 1, source);\
        rewind(source);\
    } while (0)
```

which you'd use as

```
            READ_AT_POSITION(dat, i, sajz, &tx);
```

And the compiler will turn it into your original version.

Note that a good compiler will probably do that with the function as well.

#### Better names

The only way that I know what `sajz` and `dat` do is from looking at their declarations.  Good names should balance being easy to write (e.g. `size`) with being descriptive (`size_of_each_datum` or `size_of_float`).  Perhaps `datum_size` instead of `sajz`.

Similar problem with `tjmh` and `tx`.  Neither name tells me anything about what they do.

Consider changing `h` to `gap_size`.  Yes, `h` is a standard name in a shellsort (as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort#Description)), but will most people remember that if they see it?

#### Reusability

Rather than writing this directly into `main` consider making a function.  E.g.

```
void sort_floats_in_file(FILE *source, size_t datum_size);
```

You could generalize this by passing in a comparison function.

```
void sort_in_file(FILE *source, size_t datum_size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void*));
```

However, that can add unnecessary overhead in simple cases like this.  Perhaps the compiler takes care of that.  Perhaps not.

#### Robustness

You say

> ```
>     size_t sajz = sizeof(float); // for convenience
> ```

And later

> ```
>     float tjmh, tx;
> ```

Consider flipping the order around and saying

```
    float tjmh, tx;
    size_t sajz = sizeof tjmh; // for convenience
```

Then if you change the data type of `tjmh` and `tx`, `sajz` will change to match automatically.  As is, it would be easy to forget and only change in the one place.

Similarly,

> ```
>     float a;
>     if (dat)
>     {
>         a = 2.00;
>         fwrite(&a, sizeof(float), 1, dat);
> ```

Consider rewriting this as

```
    if (dat)
    {
        test_write(2.00, dat);
```

with

```
void test_write(float a, FILE *dat)
{
    fwrite(&a, sizeof a, 1, dat);
}
```

Not only is this less typing, it avoids the problem of changing the type in one place and not the other.  Admittedly there's some extra work to write the function, but the reduction per test case should cover it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the write up!


**Robustnes, Reusability**
Since this was just a test assignment those factor were not crucial. But your points are still very  valid. I especially like the part about the macro.

**Better names** 
English is not my first language, so `sajz` kind of appropriate, I should have changed it before posting, sorry. Also, `tj` was `j temporary` and `tjmh` was `j minus h temporary` since I needed values at those positions (a comment would have been helpful I admit).

Comment: **Robustness** No particular comment here, all great advice. Especially the `sizeof(variable)` instead of `sizeof(float)`. I actually use this, but didn't use it here.

Comment: Also, why did you use the name `datum` for the variable name?

Comment: @smrdo_prdo  `datum` is the singular form of `data`.  It's just a moderately generic name for a single element.  I prefer it when dealing with the value.  I'd use `element` for a structural element, e.g. a node in a linked list.

Comment: Ohhhh, I did not know that. I came upon it a couple of times when reading stuff on the net, but never found out what it means. Thanks!

Comment: "Note that a good compiler will probably do that with the function as well." Wouldn't you need to set that function as `inline` for the compiler to do that?

Comment: @user6245072  No.  Most compilers actually ignore `inline` and make their own decisions about what to inline and what not.  The `inline` keyword is used to indicate that [identical function prototypes should be ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7418299) rather than cause a compiler error.  Even prior to that, compilers have always been able to choose to inline a function if their rules found it best.  The only kind of function that it can't inline is one that is defined in another compilation unit.

Answer (score 6):

#### Actually loads file into memory

By virtue of using `fread` and `fwrite`, you are using buffered I/O and you are actually loading a large part of the file into memory.  In fact, for your small test case, the entire file will be loaded into memory on the first `fread`.  To avoid this, you either need to:

1. Use `read()` and `write()` instead.
2. Turn buffering off using `setvbuf()`.

#### Be kind, rewind?

Your calls to `rewind()` are unnecessary because you always use `fseek(..., SEEK_SET)` which sets the file position from the start of the file.  So you can just remove all your calls to `rewind()`.

Comment: There's a tight upper bound on how much total memory will be used at any one time by stdio buffers.  So this is an in-place sort that uses O(1) space to sort an arbitrary sized file.  That should satisfy the spirit of the assignment.  If you want to avoid ending up with the whole file in memory (in the pagecache) you'd need to `open(..., O_RDRW|O_DIRECT)` to use direct I/O (problematic since IIRC you can only read / write whole pages), or use [`madvise(MADV_DONTNEED)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) to flush the kernel's disk cache.  Upvoted for rewind, though.

Comment: Unclear why suggest `read()` instead of `fread()` as post is not system specific and `read()` is not in the standard C library.  Suppose `read()` is _likely_ to exist.

Comment: I figured out the part about `rewind` after I posted this.

Comment: As per your first advice, since `read()` is not a part of the C standard library we were not allowed to use it. Actually we didn't learn about it at all. I don't have that much knowledge about the buffer size of `stdio`. But as @PeterCordes mentioned, it is in the spirit of the assignment. I will look in to that non the less. Thanks.

Comment: @smrdo_prdo: I wouldn't worry about it.  Just let stdio use its small buffers.  The point of the assignment is that the program doesn't *need* to load the whole data set into memory, not that it actively avoids doing so even when it's so small it happens by accident.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, the assignment didn't say there was no RAM (is that even possible?), but only that we could not load the whole file into memory. `stdio` buffers work with what they have I guess. And this program is supposed to work with a potentially very large file, which it does. So it's cool.

Comment: @PeterCordes Since it's C, there probably exists a way to completely avoid buffering. But that was not the point here :)

Comment: @smrdo_prdo: 1. Yes, it's of course possible to disable input and output buffering for a stream, and JS1's answer says how.  3. Your program really *does* load the whole file into memory, but only for small inputs.  IDK where you got the "no RAM" idea.  3. No, it's not possible to implement C on something that doesn't have RAM or something analogous.  C requires being able to take the address of almost anything.  (A CPU can have all the RAM it needs built-in, on the same silicon, so it doesn't need any external DRAM chips, but that's not the same thing).

Answer (score 3):

Additions to previous 2 fine answers

1. Check I/O results.  Robust check for errors, especially I/O.  Code does use `if (dat == NULL)`, which is good.  Consider checking other file I/O.

   ```
   size_t sajz = sizeof(float); // for convenience 
   int n; // total number of floats in the file
   ... 
   // fseek(dat, 0, SEEK_END);
   // n = ftell(dat)/sajz;
   // rewind(dat);

   if (fseek(dat, 0, SEEK_END)) Handle_Error();
   long pos = ftell(dat);
   if (pos == -1) Handle_Error();
   n = pos/sajz;
   rewind(dat);  // No error return
   ```
2. Use `long` rather than `int`.  Code is limited to files `LONG_MAX` or less in size as code uses `long ftell()`.  Yet code mixes `int` with `long` with various calculations.  This only makes a difference when 1) `INT_MAX < LONG_MAX`, and 2) the file is huge.  Yet this is precisely the scenario to use an in-place sort: when the file is huge.

   ```
   // int n; // total number of floats in the file
   // ...
   // int i,j,h;

   long n; // total number of floats in the file
   ...
   long i,j,h;
   ```
3. Hidden compare: `tx < tjmh` in `for (; j>=h && tx < tjmh; j -= h)`.  Suggest un-hiding it.  The central computation of the **entire** code is this compare.

   ```
   // for (; j>=h && tx < tjmh; j -= h)

   for (; j>=h && cmp(tx, tjmh); j -= h) {
   // or 
   for (; j>=h; j -= h) {
     if (tx < tjmh) break;
   ```
4. Consider that code may want another compare.  Example: With typical floating point, Not-a-number and -0.0 may occur.  How will your code sort that, if `<` is not to coding goals?  Perhaps a helper function.

   ```
   int cmp_lt(float f1, float f2) {
     // first 3 if's return a result when f1, f1 are well ordered. (Neither NaN)
     if (f1 < f2) return 1;
     if (f1 > f2) return 0;
     if (f1 == f2) {
       if (f1 == 0.0f && (signbit(f1) != signbit(f2)) {
         // f1 and f2 are both some 0.0 (one + and one -)
         // let -0.0 be "less than" +0.0
         return signbit(f1) == 0;
       }
       // Consider then equal
       return 0;
     }
     // at least 1 of f1,f2 is a NaN
     return isnan(f2);  // Consider f1 "less than" f2 when f2 is NaN
   }

   for (; j>=h && cmp_lt(tx, tjmh); j -= h) {
   ```

Comment: I understand points 1 and 2. Can you explain what do you mean by hidden compare? For point 4 I have to read and learn a bit. Thanks!

Comment: @smrdo_prdo The point of code is to sort a file.  The _important_ code to sorting is the compare. The code `tx < tjmh` should be highlighted or made more obvious.  When looking at the code, it was "hidden" in that it takes some time to find.

Comment: Ohhh, I see, got it. Never came across that before (nor would I think that by myself) . Thanks again!